# Spring Authorization Server 0.2.2, how to disable a default authentication provider like (OAuth2TokenRevocation) and override it with a custom one?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using the new Spring Authorization Server 0.2.2 and I want to change the logic of the `OAuth2TokenRevocationAuthenticationProvider` and make my own implementation for the Token Revocation endpoint.

I added a new **`CustomRevocationAuthenticationProvider`**

```
public class CustomRevocationAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        //My implementation
        try {

        //My implementation

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_CLIENT);
        }

        //My implementation
    }


@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return OAuth2TokenRevocationAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
}
```

and I added this provider to the `SecurityFilterChain` like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authenticationProvider(new CustomRevocationAuthenticationProvider())
                .build();
    }
```

It works good but when I throw a `OAuth2AuthenticationException` in my implementation, the default `OAuth2TokenRevocationAuthenticationProvider` get executed and return `200 OK` response.

**is there any way to disable the default oauth2 provider from handling my exception and getting executed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. Since we're working on reference documentation, this is a good topic and I'll make a note to cover it in the configuration overview.

Take a look at [OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/ccf4a2de6e210cb2d3250dd38f5accdf8885284f/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java#L59-L72). When customizing Spring Authorization Server, you will typically need to copy that code and use the configurer directly. Here's an example:

```java
OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> authorizationServerConfigurer =
    new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<>();
authorizationServerConfigurer.tokenRevocationEndpoint(tokenRevocationEndpoint -> tokenRevocationEndpoint
    .authenticationProvider(new CustomRevocationAuthenticationProvider())
);

// ...

http.apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works fine now for the Revocation Endpoint,
but what about Introspection Endpoint, I can't find the same way to override it.
I saw that when I return OAuth2TokenIntrospectionAuthenticationToken object from my implementation the default one is not called, It will be called only if I throw an Exception but here we always put (active=false) when any exception happened so I think we don't need to throw exceptions.
But I am not sure about this behavior, can you confirm is there any other way to make sure that the default IntrospectionProvider doesn't get called?

Comment: It's not yet customizable, unfortunately. See [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/493) to follow progress. Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Hello Steve, I posted a new question related to the revocation authentication provider, can you please check it? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78045586/hot-to-disable-the-default-oauth2tokenrevocationauthenticationprovider-in-spring