# How to disable the default OAuth2TokenRevocationAuthenticationProvider in spring authorization server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server, revoke-token

I implemented a custom revocation authentication provider and added it to the `OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer`, and it works fine. then we decided to add the revoke token endpoint to the `permitAll()` endpoints and remove the security check because we want to use it without sending clientId and clientSecret, then when I am throwing an exception from the custom revocation authentication provider, the default one get excuted and then the authentication check in the default one throws `OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_CLIENT)`.
Even if I throw OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_TOKEN) from my custom revocation authentication provider.

This is my code:

```
 authorizationServerConfigurer.tokenRevocationEndpoint(tokenRevocationEndpoint -> tokenRevocationEndpoint.authenticationProvider(new RevocationAuthenticationProvider(revokedTokenRepository)));
```

```
public class RevocationAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2TokenRevocationAuthenticationToken tokenRevocationAuthentication =
                (OAuth2TokenRevocationAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        JWTClaimsSet claims;
        try {
            claims = getTokenClaims(tokenRevocationAuthentication);
            if (isCustomValidationCheck(claims)) {
                throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_TOKEN);
            }
// Custom implementation
}
}
```

if the `isCustomValidationCheck` method return true I am getting a response message "invalid_client" not invalid_token because the default logic is always checking for the `clientPrincipal` in the `OAuth2AuthenticationProviderUtils.getAuthenticatedClientElseThrowInvalidClient()`